# Which is better: ui-grid angular or smart table angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

The requirement is to have a custom CSS, sortable columns, global search.

A few apprehensions related to UI-grid:

- The layout of UI-grid is based on divs, while that of Smart table is
  like that of a normal table.
- Also, if the UI-grid CSS is not used,
  then many divs are to be changed to table-row and table-cell.
- In my case, the UI-grid extends beyond the width of parent container.
  (There is no padding/margin getting exceeded). I resorted to hiding
  overflow, but it is more of a hack.

Questions related to Smart Table:

- Can we have a structure similar to columnDefs to define column
  attributes?
- Is it less powerful than UI-grid?
- Does it run into issues?

Which of these 2 tables should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AngularJS TableView](https://github.com/w3core/AngularJS-TableView)
[image]